# Node GET method doesn't accept combination of constants and strings

Tags: node.js

I have created an environmental variable that I want to use by concatenating it with a string for api route. I seem to have defined everything but for some reason combining both generates an error but using each of them separately works fine and I don't understand why. For example this works

``` app.get(``${api}``,(req, res) => {}); ``` or `` app.get(`/products`,(req, res) => {}); ``

but `` app.get(`${api}/products`,(req, res) => {}); `` doesn't work

.env

```
API_URL = /api/v1/
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
let app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

const api = process.env.API_URL;

app.get(`${api}/products`, (req, res) => {
  const product = {
    id: 1,
    name: "shoes",
  };
  res.send(product);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(api);
  console.log("Server is running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

**ERROR** : Cannot GET /api/v1/products

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I get the following : Cannot GET /api/v1/products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring a route for `/api/v1//products`. Notice the double-slash in there.

Either remove the trailing slash from your environment variable, or remove the leading slash from `/products`.